# Sub report export in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How to Sub report Export using vb.net 2008?

Main report already Properly export as PDF Format.

But my need also export as pdf is -
**2 no and 3 No report**

how this possible?
[image]

**Code is-**

`Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ExecuteQuery("Execute dbo.BatchWiseIssue @OrderID=" & OrderGridLookUpEdit.EditValue, cnn)
        filterstring = "{Command.OrderID} = " & OrderGridLookUpEdit.EditValue
        'Call Report
        Dim MyReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument = New OrderAllStatusSummery_2
        ShowReport(MyReport, filterstring, CrystalReportViewer1)
        'Export
        Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
        Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
        Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "D:\Imrul_XML\PDF\crystalExport.pdf"
        CrExportOptions = MyReport.ExportOptions
        With CrExportOptions
            .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
            .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
            .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
            .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
        End With
        MyReport.Export()
        Dim pdfFile As String = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName
        'Call Outlok
        Dim Outl As Object
        Outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        If Outl IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim omsg As Object
            omsg = Outl.CreateItem(0)
            omsg.subject = "Hello"
            omsg.body = "Dear Sir," & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "plz check this file......." & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "With Best Regards," & vbNewLine & "------------" & vbNewLine & NameTextBox.Text & vbNewLine & DesignationTextBox.Text & vbNewLine & "Sparkle Knit Composite Ltd." & vbNewLine & "Asulia, Savar, Bangladesh"
            omsg.Attachments.Add(pdfFile)
            omsg.Display(False)
        End If
    End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a new data table and set subreport datasource as below:

```
 Dim DT As DataTable = "Your Method or Query"
 cryRpt.Subreports("Sub Report Name as in report").SetDataSource(DT)
```

then you can use one line to export to PDF or MS- Word what ever you need as

```
  cryRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "Your File Name")
```

Comment: Assalalualikum, Dear vai, plz write me details code.